# Google Play Games leaderboard custom

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-games

I want to implement this 
"my ranking : Top 13% (25034 rank)"

What I've tried↓

```
Social.LoadScores("CgkI1...", scores => {...})
```

: "scores.Length" was returned only up to 25.

```
ILeaderboard lb = Social.CreateLeaderboard();
lb.id = "CgkI1...";
uint max_player = lb.maxRange;
```

: failed..

I don't know in leaderboard player count and my rank.
please help me what can I do..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I succeeded on my own:

```
        ILeaderboard lb =  PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.CreateLeaderboard();
        lb.id = "CgkI1...";
        lb.userScope = UserScope.Global;
        lb.range = new Range(1,10);
        lb.timeScope = TimeScope.AllTime;


        lb.LoadScores(scores =>
        {
            uint all_player = lb.maxRange;
            int my_rank = lb.localUserScore.rank;
            decimal percent = (decimal)my_rank / (decimal)all_player;

            text.text = scores.ToString() + "\nAllPlayer: " + all_player + "\nMyRank: " + my_rank + "\nMyScore: " +lb.localUserScore.value.ToString() + "\nPercent: " + percent + "%";
        });
```

[image: t]